# Switch any program to kiosk mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, autohotkey, kiosk

Sometimes friends or even unknown people visit me and we are doing something on my computer. I often find myself in the situation when I want to leave the computer but I don't completely trust the people around it, and I don't want to lock the computer.

Imagine the situation: I am having the party and we decide to play some music or run a movie either in VLC player, internet browser or in other application.

Then I want to leave the computer, but I don't want to lock it, so other people can use it or watch the playing video, or finish whatever we were doing.

But I do not want the people to get to OS, get to other applications and files.

I would like to know the way how to switch any application to kiosk mode, without previous preparations. Namely: I don't want to turn everything off or log off. I would like just to prevent switching programs with alt-tab, prevent starting other applications from the start menu, with Win+R keyboard shortcut and in other ways. I imagine, that I can turn the kiosk mode off with a secret password.

The closest thing I found is the ClearLock application. I am using keyboard shortcut to start the app. This locks the screen but still shows the contents. - It allows me to play video but doesn't allow anyone to do anything with the computer until the password is entered.
That is fine. But I would like the people to control the application that has the focus and just prevent losing the focus of active window until the password is entered.

Note that even partial solution is better than any solution. The unknown people are often friends which might not find or abuse the security holes which might exist in partial solution.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have a Kiosk mode.  So what third-party application are you using that adds that feature?

Comment: @Ramhound I am not avare of any application which can be used for this. I would like to know some.

Comment: There is an entire industry for Kiosk software on Windows.  Per the rules of this site I cannot make a software recommendation.

Comment: The solution you don't want is the solution - log out and log in the limited, restricted "guest account for parties."

Answer (score -1):

Partial Solution

The programs you mentioned have a fullscreen option (e.g. F11 on Chrome). You could use AutoHotKey to disable obvious key combinations to escape the full screen mode, such as Alt-Tab, Ctrl-Shift-Esc, F11.

Download AutoHotKey and make a plain text file called `DisableKeys.ahk` and place something like this inside the file:

```
; Pressing Alt-Tab will do nothing
!+tab::
return

; Pressing Ctrl-Alt-Tab will do nothing
^!tab::
return

; Pressing Alt-F4 will do nothing
^F4::
return    

; Pressing F11 will do nothing
F11::
return

; Pressing Shift and X will exit this script!!
#x::ExitApp
```

There are some ways I can think of to escape this, but perhaps this might help restore some order in your domain.

Let me know if you want me to test/flesh out this option!

**edit** answer was downvoted, but without criticism. This won't result in better quality answers.